# Cannot create instance of ISWiProject

Tags: c#-4.0, installshield

I am using InstallShield 2016 SP1. I am trying to set some attributes for my installation project through C#. I got Installation automation code from the following link : 
http://codecontext.blogspot.in/2012/04/installshield-automation-using-c.html.

I created a Sample console application and it is working fine. When I integrate the same code with my main application I am unable to create the instance of ISWiProject at BuildProject() (You can refer the above code for reference). The error which I encountered is stated as below :

Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800a0035 Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0035 (CTL_E_FILENOTFOUND).

I also changed the platform target to x86, still not luck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This COM server can only be called from a 32 bit process.